# How to skip grub and continue with next boot option?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I want to create a Grub menu entry that, instead of loading an Operating System, skips the Grub loader entirely and continues with the next boot option. The official documentation doesn't seem to give an option to do this.

All my research has only lead me to answers on how to skip the boot menu and boot instantly, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Once you're in grub, you can't "exit" grub and boot from the next loader. It's already _booted_ into grub, essentially. You might want to choose the boot device from BIOS/UEFI instead.

Comment: That's the issue, I have a dual-boot going on with an EFI and a BIOS system with a BIOS-Grub. I've read that there is not a way too boot EFI once you've loaded into BIOS. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Generally you choose whether to boot BIOS or UEFI (or UEFI can boot BIOS sometimes in CSM mode, depending on support for it in your UEFI/BIOS settings) but once you've booted into a device (like an SSD with Grub in its MBR for BIOS or GRUB in its EFI folder for UEFI) then you can't "un-boot". Depending on the bootloader you might be able to chainload into another drive (like Grub lets you do) but choosing EFI over BIOS after that point is entirely up to the bootloader, and I'm inclined to think BIOS GRUB has no support for EFI and vice versa...perhaps convert BIOS OSes to EFI if possible?

Comment: I ended up backing up my Qubes and reinstalling in EFI mode. Was a pain, but worked. It's probably better to do a clean reinstall than a janky conversion...